# What method to call in order to obtain notification value from the server in a GATT connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

My program can successfully receive notification from a server device, with my android device being the client, of course.

But now I'm having this bit of a embarrassing problem: I know my android program has received the notification, around 23 bytes or so, but I don't know how to obtain it, using for example an char array. I looked up an example online, but it doesn't appear to be something desirable to me, because the example uses intent filter and broadcasts, and simply extract extra data with this line:

```
DataReceivedOverGATT = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
```

before that, the example shoves the characteristic, the whole characteristic it seems, which just received a notification into a broadcast with this line:

```
broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
```

I do not want to use broadcast, I want to process the data just received on the spot, inside callback

```
onCharacteristicRead
```

of method

```
 BluetoothGattCallback
```

which method should I use? I looked up getValue, but it appears that it reads the static characteristic information (the stuff you get once you discover the characteristic, with or without receiving notification).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have understood the bluetooth-lowenergy .

if you want to get value, you should process the data onto `onCharacteristicChanged()` callback.

if you don't, it means that notification is failing.

I just think you should read [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) again.

Comment: Yes, how do I obtain data in that callback?

Comment: `byte[] data = characteristic.getValue()`

Comment: Huh? But doesn't that return the STATIC characteristic value, instead of what you just received from notification (the 30 bytes or so short message)?

Comment: Have you checked your LE device ? Or use nrfConnect APP verified your LE device ? If yes , I'm no idea

Comment: What does the method you mentioned do actually?